# incorrect google link to mathoverflow

Tags: bug, status-norepro

Whenever I google MO, I find that the link https://mathoverflow.net/ leads to a page that reads

> This site is down for maintenance
>
> This site is currently down for maintenance. Please check back in a few minutes.

The only way I seem to get to the new MO is through the URL https://mathoverflow.net/questions. Does anyone else experience this? If so, will this be rectified soon?

(I didn't see another question on meta that asks this precise question, but perhaps I didn't look hard enough.)

Comment: Did you try to refresh the page in your browser (or clean cache and related things)? Also is the problem just via google or also if you give the url you mention manually (I assume the latter but am not certain.) Personally, I do not have the problem (neither directly nor via Google).

Comment: Thanks, quid. It was through google, but apparently I hadn't cleared the cache before (thought I had). The problem is fixed now (sorry for noise, but I'll leave this question up just in case it helps anyone else).

Comment: The link works fine for me. Btw, you can check if a site works or not using http://isup.me/

Comment: I bet SE was pushing some fixes and you just got caught up with them at the wrong time. Has happened to me at times.

Comment: Sounds like a DNS issue. I had a similar problem for the first day or so after migration.

Answer (score 1):

Tagging this as no-repro since it was a local issue - ping me here if it ever comes up again.  It was *very* likely a combination of browser cache and the move.